# Windows 10: Network Bridge - How to specify statis IP for Ethernet adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, bridging

I have a face recognition machine(FRM) for recording employees attendance and we usually connect to the network to get the data from the machine. The software is installed on the server.

Now, I installed the software in a laptop and connected the FRM directly to the laptop. I have used a cross cable to make the connection. To make the cross-cable connection working, I make the IP of both FRM and laptop's ethernet adapter as static. The IP addresses will look like as follows:

FRM IP
IP: 192.168.1.2
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1

Laptop IP ( Ethernet adapter)
IP: 192.168.1.10
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1

**This works pretty well. But...**

The issue is that I'm not able to use the FRM and wifi together. When I connect wifi, I cannot ping the FRM's IP.

I tried network bridging ( but I'm not into networking, I'm a software developer). But after bridging, how can I specify static IP address to the Ethernet adapter so that the laptop can communicate with FRM.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both LAN and Wi-Fi adapters have IP interfaces (addresses) in the same 192.168.1.0/24 -subnet. That's a no-go, only one IP interface per subnet is allowed in this context.

To resolve the issue the only way is to configure the LAN interface and the FRM to another IP subnet; for example FRM to 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0, and the LAN to 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0. The IP address of the LAN adapter is the default gateway for the FRM.

Bridging with Windows Wi-Fi adapter only works when it's used as a hotspot.